# htaccess redirect to HTTPS except a few urls

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new to the htaccess redirect stuff but want to do smth special - and I dont know whats the recommend way and dont know if this is still possible or not.

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now every URL is redirected to the HTTPS version - this is fine and necessery. But now there are a few exceptions.

For example these urls HAS to be HTTP instead of HTTPS:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/another/url/which/has/to/be/http
http://www.mywebsite.com/and_again?var=a
```

Is it possible to solve this with the htaccess and when its possible maybe you can send me a reference link or describe how to do this.

**Edit**

I now have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(/commerce_paypal/*)\s [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The goal is that **every** (!) url gets redirected to HTTPS except ANY url which has commerce_paypal at the beginning.

For example:

```
mydomain.com/commerce_paypal  <- http
mydomain.com/commerce_paypal/smth/else <- http
mydomain.com/what/ever <- https
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can have a `RewriteCond` to add exceptions in the `http->http` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force https:// for all except some selected URLs    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/commerce_paypal/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /commerce_paypal/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now have this snippet to force the exceptions: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(/commerce_paypal/*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]             As you see the plan is to force that commerce_paypal is not HTTPS anymore. There a a few commerce_paypal URLS so I typed in "commerce_paypal/*" so that every url parts after / can be possible but has to be HTTP. But this does not work ... any ideas ?

Comment: Rather than comments can you post the code in the question to make it readable.

Comment: Hmm your regex was incorrect. See my updated answer with the corrected version.

Comment: @anubhava, your solution worked locally for me, but my staging environment is behind a load balancer and is getting stuck in an infinite redirect loop.  I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` to catch all URLs except for my one excluded URL and send it to HTTPS.  Then in the second block to redirect my one URL to HTTP, I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https` per the recommendation here: https://docs.acquia.com/article/redirecting-traffic-between-http-and-https-acquia-cloud

Comment: This worked for me. But I would I exclude more folders instead of just 1 ? I tried just copying RewriteCond line but that did not work. Thanks !

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /commerce_paypal|page2|page3/ [NC]` should work. If it doesn't then please create a new question and I will answer.

Comment: Same code I have used but showing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/commerce_paypal/ [NC]
```

worked for me. I tried many similar condition rewrites without luck.