# Hyperlinks to external urls are getting replaced to https in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

Hi my Wordpress website is recently upgraded with SSLCertificate.In order to resolve mixed content errors i installed a plugin (HTTP / HTTPS Remover )  to force http to https.
This site is working fine,no mixed content errors but *the external urls links in the site as hyperlink (http://walktohealth.org) are getting replaced with https*.
How to solve this issue.

PFB .htaccess code ;

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]g(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^g(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^e(\d+)[-/].*[-/]g(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^e(\d+)[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^g(\d+)[-/].*[-/]e(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^g(\d+)[-/]e(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]g(\d+)[-/]e(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*[-/]e(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]e(\d+)[-/].*[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]e(\d+)[-/]g(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomainName\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomainName.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

1.When adding external domain name (***http***://walktohealth.org/)in Menu
[image]

2.After adding menu with external url and  when we click the widget menu it is changing to ***https***://walktohealth.org/

[image]

3.After redirecting to external http site, it will be like below
[image]

4..whynopadlock.com/results
[image]

Comment: replace all mixed contents in the database and uninstall bad plugins like this

Comment: Please use the better search replace plugin to replace all the http to https.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Plugin also provide the dry run so you can easily understand and see how many http URL in the content. Also provide the good database table selection functionality.

Comment: @Tobias There is no mixed content issue in my site.Issue is that external links are also redirecting as https even if it is not.

Comment: @Dolar PFA screenshots to explain the issue am facing.

Answer (score 0):

To force change the url from http to https, please backup your .htaccess file from wordpress root. and create the new .htaccess file at the root and paste the below code in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: I did the same as u suggested but it is not solving the issue

Comment: same question i visted previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426893/htaccess-redirect-to-https-except-a-few-urls

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support

I got an answer for my question which am explaining below

[Click here for detailed post on wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/how-to-add-a-custom-link-to-a-menu-with-a-url-that-is-relative-to-the-blog-url)

> On a custom URL in the Menu setup it is possible to use relative links
>   to the [blogurl]. The secret is to start the relative URL with a
>   single /. When a single / starts the custom URL the system will not
>   prepend the typical http:// and then the current blogURL will be
>   generated in the target URL at execution time.

EXAMPLE
If you want to go to your home page, simply put / as the custom URL

If you want to go to the index page in the folder bbforums then put /bbforums as the custom URL.

This allows you to move a site to a test domain without having to hard code the new blogURL in all the custom links for the menus.

For Example:
If my blog is http://example.com and I want to test it in a subdomain http://test.example.com the site can be moved between test and production without menu problems using the relative URL convention noted above. I have successfully tested this approach using the XCloner plugin to move the site.